# GIS-based reporting and maintenance tool

Tags: java, report, gis, crud, interactive

### Background

Conceptually, I am looking for a tool, or suite of software tools that can be readily integrated to help browse data using a GIS-based map (such as Google Maps). The proposed architecture resembles, but is not limited to, the following:

[image]

The technologies shown above are not fixed. For example, if OpenGEO can eliminate many of the components while adding others that are not listed (such as authentication and authorization), that would be most helpful.

Essentially, the architecture boils down to:

```
Map -> Filter sites -> Select sites -> CRUD
```

And:

```
Map -> Filter sites -> Select sites -> Summary Reports
```

The following sections describes these two problems in more detail, using a hypothetical (broad-brushstroke) example.

### Problem - CRUD

In the first screen, the user is prompted to filter by some arbitrary criteria (team names, regions, skills, equipment, and more) and select some sites:

[image]

The sites that match the filtered options are shown on the map and the user is then presented with a number of options that can be used to edit data:

[image]

If the user chooses Personnel, the system provides a CRUD screen:

[image]

The CRUD screens can be fairly complex, having simple code tables to drive them, such as:

[image]

### Problem - Report

The second part of the problem is very similar to the first, but instead of visiting CRUD screens, the user can choose to generate reports:

[image]

Note that the user has already selected the sites for reporting. If the user selects the equipment option, a report is generated with summary data:

[image]

### Question

What off-the-shelf software tool(s) can provide most (if not all) of these features?

Note: The interaction need not be exactly as shown, but the main use cases must be possible.

#### Use Case 1 - Populate Database

1. Define regions on a map.
2. Put sites [building locations] on a map.
3. Insert data (for each site).

#### Use Case 2 - Selection

1. System shows a map.
2. User filters by region and other criteria.
3. User selects sites.
4. System provides options (maintenance or reports).

#### Use Case 3 - Maintenance

1. User selects maintenance.
2. System presents complex CRUD.
3. User can add, edit, or delete data.

#### Use Case 4 - Reports

1. User selects report.
2. User selects type of report to generate.
3. System generates summary report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[m-Power](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/products/index.html) can handle everything you've mentioned above.  It's a web application development tool that is built on open architecture and integrates easily with other software.  Here's a link to a diagram of [m-Power's technology stack](http://www.mrc-productivity.com/products/specs.html) if you want to see its architecture.

Also, here are a few links to demo applications built with m-Power that are similar to what you've described above:

[Google Maps Application](http://crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.I00190s): Plots data on a Google map. Can easily integrate with the Database CRUD application or the reporting application to create the application you mentioned above.

[Maintain order truck assignment (with map)](http://crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.R00170s?run=2): Lets users update their database using drag-and-drop or by selecting any item on the map.   Can also easily integrate with the Database CRUD application or the reporting application to create the application you mentioned above.

[Database CRUD Application](http://www.crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.M00020s): I list this application because it can be integrated into the above mapping applications to create the database CRUD features found in the example you described above.

[Basic report](http://www.crazybikes.com/mrcjava/servlet/CBB2E.R00060s?run=1&S_SHIPYR=1&S_CLASS=1): I list this application because it can also integrate with the mapping applications to create the reporting features of the example you described above.

Those four apps most closely resemble the apps listed in your question, but you can also check out other applications in that demo site to get a better idea of what else m-Power can build.  It's also worth noting that m-Power has no run-time or distribution fees, so you can embed and distribute applications at no additional cost.